# modular Sinatra App, setting error handling & configuration globally

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I am using Sinatra to build a small Ruby API, and I would like to get some of the errors and configurations set to work at a global level so that i don't need to set them at the start of each of the classes.

My structure is this:

content_api.rb

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/namespace'
require 'sinatra/json'
require 'service_dependencies'
require 'api_helpers'
require 'json'

module ApiApp
  class ContentApi < Sinatra::Base

    helpers Sinatra::JSON
    helpers ApiApp::ApiHelpers
    include ApiApp::ServiceDependencies

    before do
      content_type :json
    end

    get '/' do
      content = content_service.get_all_content
      content.to_json
    end

    get '/audio' do
      package =content_service.get_type 'Audio'
      package.to_json
    end

    get '/video' do
      package =content_service.get_type 'Video'
      package.to_json
    end

    get '/document' do
      package =content_service.get_type 'Document'
      package.to_json
    end

  end
end
```

config.ru:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift *Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/src/**')]
$LOAD_PATH.unshift *Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/src/api/**')]

require 'content_api'
require 'package_api'
require 'utility_api'
require 'sinatra/base'


configure do
  set :show_exceptions => false
end

error { |err| Rack::Response.new([{'error' => err.message}.to_json], 500, {'Content-type' => 'application/json'}).finish }

Rack::Mount::RouteSet.new do |set|
    set.add_route ApiApp::ContentApi, {:path_info => %r{^/catalogue*}}, {}, :catalogue
    set.add_route ApiApp::PackageApi, {:path_info => %r{^/package*}}, {}, :package
    set.add_route ApiApp::UtilityApi, {:path_info => %r{^/health_check*}}, {}, :health_check
  end
```

When I run this, it will run okay, but when I force a 500 error (shut down MongoDb) I get a standard html type error that states:

```
<p id="explanation">You're seeing this error because you have
enabled the <code>show_exceptions</code> setting.</p>
```

If I add the

```
configure do
      set :show_exceptions => false
    end

    error { |err| Rack::Response.new([{'error' => err.message}.to_json], 500, {'Content-type' => 'application/json'}).finish }
```

inside the content_api.rb file, then I get a JSON error returned as I would like to receive.
however, as I am building this modular, I don't want to be repeating myself at the top of each class.

Is there a simple way to make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be to reopen `Sinatra::Base` and add the code there:

```
class Sinatra::Base
  set :show_exceptions => false

  error { |err|
    Rack::Response.new(
      [{'error' => err.message}.to_json],
      500,
      {'Content-type' => 'application/json'}
    ).finish
  }
end
```

This is probably not advisable though, and will cause problems if your app includes other non-json modules.

A better solution might be to create a [Sinatra extension](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html) that you could use in your modules.

```
module JsonExceptions

  def self.registered(app)
    app.set :show_exceptions => false

    app.error { |err|
      Rack::Response.new(
        [{'error' => err.message}.to_json],
        500,
        {'Content-type' => 'application/json'}
      ).finish
    }
  end
end
```

You would then use it by registering it in your modules:

```
# require the file where it is defined first
class ContentApi < Sinatra::Base
  register JsonExceptions
  # ... as before
end
```

Comment: Thanks, creating it as an extension worked a treat, i think its cleaner to do it this way, as its only a repeat of a single line at the top of each class. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, inheritance:

```
class JsonErrorController < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    set :show_exceptions => false
  end

  error { |err| Rack::Response.new([{'error' => err.message}.to_json], 500, {'Content-type' => 'application/json'}).finish }

end

class ContentApi < JsonErrorController
  # rest of code follows…
end
```

From *Sinatra Up and Running* p73:

> Not only settings, but every aspect of a Sinatra class will be
>   inherited by its subclasses. This includes defined routes, all the
>   error handlers, extensions, middleware, and so on.

Comment: thanks iain, I wasn't too far off this solution myself, personally i like the idea of the extension, as we use sinatra a fair bit for apis, i have turned the extension with a custom error class into a gem for us to use internally

Comment: @Vade Sure, I think I'd probably go for an extension for just a single need like this, too. You might consider mixing the two, creating several extensions to be used in your APIs and creating an ApiController class that you could inherit from to create new APIs.